# Methods with the same name in java

Tags: java

Suppose we have an interface such as the following in java

```
public interface AnInterface
{
      public void aMethod();
}
```

and a class as follows:

```
public class AClass
{
   public void aMethod()
   {
      //bla bla bla
   }
}
```

Now I'm going to define another class such as Subclass that extends AClass and implements AnInterface, as in:

```
public class Subclass extends AClass implements AnInterface
{
   public void aMethod()
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

What does exactly aMethod() do in Subclass? Does it implement the method in AnInterface? Or does it overrides the method in AClass?

What should I do in order to make aMethod() implement the method of AnInterface?
Similarly, if I want it to override the method in AClass, what can I do with it?

Answer (score 1):

As you might have noticed, the interface method(s) does not have any body. This simply means, that a class implementing this interface *must* implement those methods, here `aMethod()`. Your class `SubClass` extends `AClass` and inherits the method `aMethod()` from it. Now implementing the `aMethod` in the `SubClass` will simply override the method from `AClass` and at the same time adhere to the interface rules. So the method in effect will be the one in the `SubClass`.

To answer your question in short: 
The `aMethod()` in Subclass currently both implements the method from `AnInterface` AND overrides it from `AClass`.

Comment: You mean that aMethod  both implements  the method in AnInterface, and overrides the method in AClass at the same time? Isn't it kind of ambiguity?

Comment: It is! But maybe `AClass` could implement the interface, and then the `SubClass` can override the method if it needs to. I think it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: An interface can be seen as a contract. If a class implements an interface, you know that it *will* have the methods of the interface, but they might be implemented differently if another class implements the interface as well. When you extend there's already some kind of implementation that you inherit, so you can easily reuse it.

Comment: Suppose one makes a little change to the mentioned code: they change the return type of AnInterface.aMethod() to int, and the return type of AClass.aMethod() to String. Now if they try to write code for aMethod() in Subclass, then the compiler returns an error in either case: in case they set the return type of Subclass.aMethod to int, the compiler complains that the return type is not compatible with that of AClass.aMethod(). Conversely in case they set the return type to String, the compiler says that the return type is not compatible with AnInterface.aMethod(). How can we solve it?

Comment: The interface is now stating that the method *must* return an int. AClass.aMethod() returns a String, and when you try to implement the interface methods in `SubClass` it is also overriding another method with a different return type, which is not a legal action. You could simply reconsider your method names to fix it.

Comment: So I think you say this is a limitation caused by java, and there is no strict way, other than to turn around this limitation by some trick. Don't you?

Comment: There can be a trick: we can derive a class, say Intermediate, from AClass that consists of a method, say intermediateMethod() that calls aMethod() in its body, and then rewrite Subclass such that it extends class Intermediate, and implements AnInterface simultaneously!

Comment: From the Java documentation it states that `Return types may vary among methods that override each other if the return types are reference types. The notion of return-type-substitutability supports covariant returns, that is, the specialization of the return type to a subtype.` [8.4.5. Method Result](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96292/discussion-between-hedayat-and-jonas-lomholdt).